# CoreData crash on mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: invalid Summary

Tags: objective-c, core-data, notifications, save, exc-bad-access

first the background:

I have a singleton which does all my CoreData related stuff on it. It's getting called from multiple threads. For each thread I generate a new MOC using always the same StoreCoordinator. I have two fetchedResultsController which need to be updated as soon as the data changes on another thread. To merge the changes I call `addControllerContextDidSave:` like in the Books Demo App.

```
- (void)addControllerContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)saveNotification {
    if (saveNotification) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *fahrzeugeContext = [fetchedFahrzeuge managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObjectContext *accountContext = [fetchedAccount managedObjectContext];
        // Merging changes causes the fetched results controller to update its results
        @try {
            if (fahrzeugeContext) [fahrzeugeContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
            if (accountContext) [accountContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {NSLog(@"Merge Notification Error: %@", e);}
    }
}
```

In some really rare cases the App crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on line `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` saying the `saveNotification` has an `invalid Summary`. (even the try-catch block doesn't work)
It happens only on really, really rare situations (e.g. once a week) so I cannot test it properly.

What can cause that and more important how to fix it. Now I'm testing with `if (saveNotification) {}` but again it can take a while till it occur again.

[image]

.

EDIT: found an older device crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 655DB451-81C1-41A6-942C-F54DD9F40FCC
CrashReporter Key:   2495494089df0a2b47c6283c14ad5f8e7895fbbe
Hardware Model:      iPhone1,2
Process:         MyApp [648]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/43E12C67-7D7D-4F30-A7E3-D83DDE0FDCC1/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-02-25 13:33:30.232 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000004
Crashed Thread:  8

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5b4a0 swtch_pri + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de59c8 sched_yield + 8
2   UIKit                           0x35a60c18 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _smoothScroll:] + 20
3   UIKit                           0x35a4a4a0 ScrollerHeartbeatCallback + 100
4   GraphicsServices                0x33e79a3c HeartbeatVBLCallback + 152
5   IOMobileFramebuffer             0x3027d864 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 124
6   IOKit                           0x307dc884 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 292
7   CoreFoundation                  0x37537e30 __CFMachPortPerform + 212
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3752f5c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 22
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3752f582 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3752182e __CFRunLoopRun + 574
11  CoreFoundation                  0x37521504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
12  CoreFoundation                  0x37521412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
13  GraphicsServices                0x33e76d1c GSEventRunModal + 188
14  UIKit                           0x3591d574 -[UIApplication _run] + 580
15  UIKit                           0x3591a550 UIApplicationMain + 964
16  MyApp                           0x000177ae 0x1000 + 92078
17  MyApp                           0x00002f68 0x1000 + 8040

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d8f974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5e2fc _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5dd68 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35e5d788 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de6970 _pthread_wqthread + 392
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35ddd2fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5b3b0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5d894 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37521f7c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37521780 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37521504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37521412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   WebCore                         0x3318bd14 RunWebThread(void*) + 524
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de5b44 _pthread_start + 364
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dd77a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5b3b0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5d894 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37521f7c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37521780 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37521504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37521412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   Foundation                      0x3517ec4e +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 210
7   Foundation                      0x3515cb8a -[NSThread main] + 42
8   Foundation                      0x35155b90 __NSThread__main__ + 908
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de5b44 _pthread_start + 364
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dd77a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d848d8 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3755aa34 __CFSocketManager + 356
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de5b44 _pthread_start + 364
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dd77a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de72fc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de6b50 _pthread_wqthread + 872
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35ddd2fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5b3b0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d5d894 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37521f7c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37521780 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37521504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37521412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   MapKit                          0x3627ec44 TileCachePrivate::runCacheThread() + 412
7   MapKit                          0x3627ea98 _runCacheThread(void*) + 4
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de5b44 _pthread_start + 364
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dd77a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de454c __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d90f70 _pthread_cond_wait + 1140
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35d90910 pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   QuartzCore                      0x33dd01fc CA::DispatchGroup::thread(void*) + 128
4   QuartzCore                      0x33d86e30 thread_fun + 20
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de5b44 _pthread_start + 364
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dd77a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 8 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x374ffa7c ___CFBasicHashFindBucket_Linear + 120
1   CoreFoundation                  0x374ff948 CFBasicHashAddValue + 352
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3750410a CFSetAddValue + 90
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3752be2a -[__NSCFSet addObject:] + 34
4   CoreData                        0x34994b72 -[NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject:mergeChanges:] + 166
5   CoreData                        0x349b3288 -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] + 1800
6   MyApp                           0x0001aa18 0x1000 + 104984
7   Foundation                      0x351663ae _nsnote_callback + 150
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3752096a __CFXNotificationPost_old + 390
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3752060a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 122
10  Foundation                      0x3515569c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
11  CoreData                        0x349a0a68 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _didSaveChanges] + 1772
12  CoreData                        0x3499b87a -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 462
13  MyApp                           0x00018e26 0x1000 + 97830
14  MyApp                           0x0001a372 0x1000 + 103282
15  MyApp                           0x00005344 0x1000 + 17220
16  Foundation                      0x3515cb8a -[NSThread main] + 42
17  Foundation                      0x35155b90 __NSThread__main__ + 908
18  libSystem.B.dylib               0x35de5b44 _pthread_start + 364
19  libSystem.B.dylib               0x35dd77a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 8 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000001    r1: 0x0018be57      r2: 0x0020fdc8      r3: 0x00000001
    r4: 0x00000002    r5: 0x001cde10      r6: 0x00000007      r7: 0x2ff780b8
    r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x2ff780e0     r10: 0x001ce3e0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x3752be09    sp: 0x2ff78074      lr: 0x374ffa50      pc: 0x374ffa7c
  cpsr: 0x20000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x40fff +MyApp armv6  <1515b6768d3049d6eef946a5e74e95ed> /var/mobile/Applications/43E12C67-7D7D-4F30-A7E3-D83DDE0FDCC1/GPS-Explorer.app/GPS-Explorer
   0xe3000 -    0xe4fff  dns.so armv6  <88b569311cca4a9593b2d670051860d1> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe29fff  dyld armv6  <617f6daf4103547c47a8407a2e0b90de> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30270000 - 0x3027bfff  ITSync armv6  <a451205e89373cbdf0832688085e8f72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x3027c000 - 0x3027efff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <f42bbbf67195a7b98d67ad021bba4784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3027f000 - 0x3038dfff  CFNetwork armv6  <d6eeee83216ee9c553134f069f37cbc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x303ef000 - 0x303f4fff  CaptiveNetwork armv6  <f41df4b358b77b29ff85e0eaea88ee1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x303f5000 - 0x30444fff  Security armv6  <cf625b4dc7ea928891313444ef64a7cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30445000 - 0x3055cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <8968ff3f62d7780bb1bd75026a7628d0> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3055d000 - 0x30561fff  ApplePushService armv6  <0560b630d26e261e205fc58942e1885c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3059d000 - 0x305a8fff  MobileWiFi armv6  <c7532e63e083a1dd2a0ef7352b85749d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x305aa000 - 0x30612fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <9d264733fc675943c082bd3b9b567b59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30613000 - 0x3064dfff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <beb473ce80390554bb4af21554522286> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3065c000 - 0x3066efff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <51e7bb18da9afa44a33e54e42fbd0707> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3066f000 - 0x306c6fff  CoreMedia armv6  <cd5e9398c161f129146931e888e1c92e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x306f0000 - 0x306fefff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <84592e96bae1a661374b0f9a5d03a3a0> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x306ff000 - 0x30729fff  PrintKit armv6  <74f9710fa01a33b5bb04c4aeabd6be7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x307d7000 - 0x3082afff  IOKit armv6  <20da5e822f21a8d0a7c5b3e149330efd> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30831000 - 0x3083bfff  AccountSettings armv6  <eca67ab04f724e1fa7c6406c88e75433> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30999000 - 0x309c5fff  DataAccess armv6  <8c045822d57a369835f5b40653a48838> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x309c6000 - 0x309f4fff  MIME armv6  <fac8f55c508ff476e07894af7abdb761> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x30a04000 - 0x30aa3fff  ProofReader armv6  <2734920b62f174c17aeeb15f371615ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x30ad6000 - 0x30b1afff  AddressBook armv6  <1f30c3370dad27331a491ba4b190813c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30b3d000 - 0x30b9cfff  CoreAudio armv6  <ccc4bace0d6eca79a32ed84d566f72e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30ba6000 - 0x32ce3fff  TextInput armv6  <3fa14e6e5749e0230becd6ea34a8da7a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x32d7d000 - 0x32d89fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <f74f359de7bbe3ccdc37fa6f332aebf4> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x32d95000 - 0x32e5cfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <429841269f8bcecd4ba3264a8725dad6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x32e5d000 - 0x32ecdfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <87b9bb47687902d9120d03d1da9eb9fc> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x32f0c000 - 0x32f1ffff  libmis.dylib armv6  <dba9c086b49bd9540930ff27211570d6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33055000 - 0x33061fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <fd0c472436b3306f5b56118c93c8a423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33062000 - 0x3306ffff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <2b68516e1321011a4efbee2947d463c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x33070000 - 0x338bffff  WebCore armv6  <aa3b6827f051da7a3494c9bee4ebe290> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x338c0000 - 0x338d4fff  MobileDeviceLink armv6  <19d66078f8cf19be558713c13612c7a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x338d5000 - 0x33a1dfff  libmecabra.dylib armv6  <fc962eeb4e6cfe4ad5ebee6fb4b1d5c1> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x33a21000 - 0x33a6afff  CoreLocation armv6  <a69399375024b2bfae8bb96e845f4fd0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x33a6b000 - 0x33ab3fff  iCalendar armv6  <fbb717874ea0ede24454a5def644ab69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x33ab4000 - 0x33ab4fff  Accelerate armv6  <cdde24a7ad004b2b2e600cd4f3ac5eb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33b32000 - 0x33b72fff  QuickLook armv6  <54400e0d48ec86c84e937e55790b9e54> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33bbc000 - 0x33c0afff  CoreText armv6  <16c9582fdffb598178287c6ce9fd6897> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33c16000 - 0x33d73fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv6  <aec6b54ffd532bb607aab4acbab679b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x33d76000 - 0x33d79fff  ActorKit armv6  <d3ec50b4a7f0257ef31baf37936dc275> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x33d85000 - 0x33e71fff  QuartzCore armv6  <77cd91ff21fe6c58c309f2c82eb95ca5> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33e72000 - 0x33e81fff  GraphicsServices armv6  <af20aba0ec96e7b7c42bb55ac763c784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33ead000 - 0x33f6efff  ImageIO armv6  <0c1b6f466667ff345f2399d8142a9d10> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33f78000 - 0x33f79fff  CoreSurface armv6  <5e290514380c626e9b0f9f9985b9dc7a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x340ac000 - 0x340bffff  Notes armv6  <acf9e548948ecb299270c8398ef297a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x34137000 - 0x34156fff  EAP8021X armv6  <fa56845b5396c3ebb368c2368331643c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x341ad000 - 0x341ebfff  ContentIndex armv6  <7f3334380acc72292571803f0b490189> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x343a0000 - 0x343bffff  Bom armv6  <f41bef81e23e2bff59155e5ce46762d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x343c0000 - 0x344bdfff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <3547c92c1efc0522b087e7f10eba7728> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x344be000 - 0x34500fff  ManagedConfiguration armv6  <397723a33c19c3487d304d69580acbfc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x34954000 - 0x34a5cfff  CoreData armv6  <6e3af4b4648ae695f8d4bc0bf5a9dba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34a6e000 - 0x34a72fff  CertUI armv6  <57c499baf9d343a78fe1b43f0f3ef997> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x34b52000 - 0x34f1ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv6  <0eb734c91165416224b98c943ff6476b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34f20000 - 0x35014fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv6  <01916d6784f4de8f3746978faae9c5fa> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35015000 - 0x35022fff  CoreVideo armv6  <7b100fd5fdf98db1cd0f0649e7f6f316> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x35023000 - 0x3507dfff  MessageUI armv6  <21bb9d93911f7015b79aef9dc6df55ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x35087000 - 0x35148fff  AddressBookUI armv6  <fea72732451610277e22a667d35ad76d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35151000 - 0x35272fff  Foundation armv6  <6bdeb19a1fcb93e2930dadb50416f881> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3529b000 - 0x352a6fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <6aa8a4ed0906a495d059ace9125f525d> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x352dc000 - 0x35342fff  libBLAS.dylib armv6  <11a3677a08175a30df1b3d66d7e0951a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35348000 - 0x353b0fff  GMM armv6  <adcdfedd491ac237b385b6c2d7f684e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x35406000 - 0x35406fff  vecLib armv6  <8f914b3e8a581d49fb21d2c0ff75be03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x35407000 - 0x3540afff  MobileInstallation armv6  <456ed7fe6dd9fcd8e78df425085b1452> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35541000 - 0x35547fff  MBX2D armv6  <fad4955cab36e0179df6f8f27d365b8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x35758000 - 0x35778fff  AppleAccount armv6  <0ef3f6564414f3ef030031ae25b28bbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x35779000 - 0x3577bfff  TextInput_de armv6  <e51cb663d64b8ced7dccfdbd3ad04591> /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_de.bundle/TextInput_de
0x35815000 - 0x3581afff  AssetsLibraryServices armv6  <224b3cf992a01814f91481244e3213eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3581b000 - 0x35877fff  libGLImage.dylib armv6  <7c1049f20c4e64591c09d3ac00c7d3ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x358bc000 - 0x358c3fff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <f470dea180ddf23886df75eb256d3888> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x358cc000 - 0x358cffff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <bed95ed187350ce27d22ed241ef892ea> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x358d3000 - 0x35d4ffff  UIKit armv6  <14ec6c926b8bda71b73136f6e1a6ac1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35d5a000 - 0x35e98fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <70571c1e697e2ae7f7a9b1a499453bb6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x35f7e000 - 0x35fc2fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <101dbbcd34cc3231a8be3fd6392556aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35fdb000 - 0x36162fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <9a1d72fa9549d83abc1e735ba37a4dc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x36167000 - 0x36178fff  DataAccessExpress armv6  <c112bd2791eb706526db25407ec117d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36179000 - 0x36255fff  WebKit armv6  <83da207070be989ba81dba3a83d5206a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x36269000 - 0x36278fff  OpenGLES armv6  <37eda5ddcff210dd321157da35a87a5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36279000 - 0x36362fff  MapKit armv6  <d28b96a0107a7822fda677ed28901c0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x363f3000 - 0x363f9fff  MobileKeyBag armv6  <2d83bf6a43bab972d77a1a6e0f3b03d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x363fa000 - 0x36483fff  Message armv6  <9ed4944d998f99e69ba81afdda659bee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x36500000 - 0x36508fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <8ed6e560e85eecfaf625219a8247aea4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x365db000 - 0x365f9fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <9c94634beea733e754dc115737b6e63c> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x36746000 - 0x3683cfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <9c44d05cc67f1ebabd795903e581724e> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3683e000 - 0x36888fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <cfc94cfa17958f2f94c9eff208a7dace> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x36889000 - 0x368b4fff  MobileSync armv6  <b42cf746d993e6765d432edf47987835> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x368b5000 - 0x3692dfff  EventKit armv6  <c1fb82d645d3bf1f2e0558cc884712e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3694c000 - 0x3694ffff  libAccessibility.dylib armv6  <74e0f77cc276a9412be268c795fdcbca> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36955000 - 0x36a1ffff  Celestial armv6  <11172a6ee53bdf067548cd4496bc5fe0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x36a20000 - 0x36a2cfff  WebBookmarks armv6  <5d1eb10d851d0362e304d9d95f016df1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x36a2d000 - 0x36a30fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <00bc60f690e6328b64e7a7b718edf45a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36a31000 - 0x36a74fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <cabbce0fa7630065dc7e7d3ca3bc616c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x36c1c000 - 0x36c26fff  AggregateDictionary armv6  <f7429444c955e4f13c6761d20032ab52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36c2b000 - 0x36de1fff  AudioToolbox armv6  <bb65e8ed531fe5923eb8ac00a7c0d87d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x36de2000 - 0x36e16fff  AppSupport armv6  <783e14db9585fd063c0c2a755cd121b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36e17000 - 0x36e2dfff  PersistentConnection armv6  <006723906b8ac250c1681a1821fbe94d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36e2e000 - 0x37140fff  GeoServices armv6  <570238d025d41838cc888a0b3f28f4b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x37141000 - 0x37184fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <207f362e707871e74a292cfd1ea7893d> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x372aa000 - 0x37477fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <21ceabd0e5de17ad4e883c85fcd34d51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x37478000 - 0x3747dfff  IOSurface armv6  <ffd66ca04dfe7d382d6961f0df3839ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3748d000 - 0x374f8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <eccd1d7183e73587b2c0aa5755a19c39> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x374f9000 - 0x375e4fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <ab0eac0ddd5b4ae1bf8541116e3c0bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3760a000 - 0x3760bfff  DataMigration armv6  <d2de7c0db77278484236669c2cdccabb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x37731000 - 0x37736fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv6  <bd1c480607cc286288db1ca1aec64180> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x377f6000 - 0x37817fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <22c6da37f3adf325f99c3a0494e04c02> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x37992000 - 0x37999fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv6  <de9b417e7278742e90b30b1ad45f31fa> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

> In some really rare cases the App
>   crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line
>   mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:
>   saying the saveNotification has an
>   invalid Summary. (even the try-catch
>   block doesn't work)

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a hard crash, not an exception, which is why the try-catch won't catch it.

Can you post the backtrace of the crash and the invalid summary message?

Overall, this sounds like a thread synchronization issue.  It sounds like you have a relatively complex concurrency model and, more likely than not, there is a synchronization bug somewhere.

Comment: sure will do when it appears again. Is there an easy way to save the complete state of crash including the relevant objects and values from debugger?

Comment: The common concurrency issue here is that you're calling mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: from a different thread than you created the target context on. e.g. you create a context on the main thread, but call mergeChanges on it from a different thread. Make sure all your calls to mergeChanges are on the context's owning thread, you can use performSelector:OnThread: to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm sure its on the same thread cause I call the save from the same context and then merge the changes from another context. btw. I have included a crash log.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple ManagedObjectContext across threads you have to lock the context before any read/write operation to ManagedObjects from this context.

This is particularly important when implementing mergeContextFromDidSaveNotification because in this case the context is used simultaneously by 2 threads. You then have to lock the context before merge in the notified thread (usually the main thread) and before any change in the background thread.

Comment: thats not quite correct MOC is not thread safe but the store coordinator is. And I'm using the didSaveNotification to merge the three different contexts (like Apple did in the books example)

Comment: Not sure how correct this answer is.  From the CoreData documentation: "There is typically no need to use locks with managed objects or managed object contexts. However, if you use a single persistent store coordinator shared by multiple contexts and want to perform operations on the persistent store coordinator, you should lock the persistent store coordinator."